# does importing unwanted feature modules in angular modules increases size or affects performance

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-lazyloading

I have got multiple features/components which are being used in different Angular modules.. currently loading them all separately

```
Module 1:
  Feature 1
  Feature 2
  Feature 3
  Feature 4

Module 2:
  Feature 3
  Feature 5

Module 3:
  Feature 1
  Feature 2
  Feature 6
  Feature 7
```

if i put all these features in a shared module and then call it in all the function modules like below:

```
Shared Module 1:
  Feature 1
  Feature 2
  Feature 3
  Feature 4
  Feature 5
  Feature 6
  Feature 7


Module 1:
  Shared Module 1

Module 2:
  Shared Module 1

Module 3:
  Shared Module 1
```

Will it cause lag or be slow as there will be many features not being used by all the modules.. for eg: Module 2 only need feature 3 and 5, but as i will be importing whole of shared module.. will it affect performance while loading Module 2.

Comment: if you're making individual exports and destructuring when importing it should be fine

like "import {Feature  1} from 'Module1'

Comment: So using shared module not required??

Comment: I guess so. I'm guessing your aim is only to import one at a time and not all?

Comment: @ShubhamShaw if you have such segregation on modules I suggest not to have 'shared' module because you just loose all benefits of having many modules. Imagine case when you creating lazy module and you need just only a few features, but you just use SharedModule instead which results to all linked modules be included into your final bundle size. Instead just import necessary modules where they are needed, this is not so painful in comparison  to benefits you get.